# Assemblies not being found

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, npgsql

The Entity Framework provider type 'Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, Npgsql.EntityFramework6.Npgsql' registered in the application config file for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'Npgsql' could not be loaded. Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is used and that the assembly is available to the running application. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information

Using Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition

Using Entity Framework 6.2 (Installed via Nuget)

Using Npgsql 4.0.4 (Installed via Nuget)

Using VSIX for npsql installed via Microsoft Marketplace

Attempting code-first EF6 / postgres.
Just about tried every combination of app.config that I have seen examples on various posts. I am obviously missing something. Please help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
     <system.data>
 <system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="Npgsql"/>
    <add name="Npgsql Data Provider" invariant="Npgsql" description=".Net Data Provider for PostgreSQL" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7"/>
  </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>  </system.data>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="CricketConnection" connectionString="server=localhost;Database=CricketGrounds;Username=postgres;Password=postgres"
      providerName="Npgsql" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
     <providers>
      <provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, Npgsql.EntityFramework6.Npgsql" />
    </providers>
 </entityFramework>

</configuration>
```

Comment: There's a provider package for EF6 for Postgres.   That package is EntityFramework6.Npgsql.   It will install a version of Npgsql, but currently the latest NuGet package is compiled against Npgsql 4.0.2.  I would remove the Npgsql reference via Nuget and add EF6.Npgql and see if it resolves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this because I hadn't installed EntityFramework6.Npgsql which (among other things) adds stuff to App.Config

```
 <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Npgsql" publicKeyToken="5d8b90d52f46fda7" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.4.0" newVersion="4.0.4.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

I still have problems but now with System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory but if I can't solve that I'll post another question.